# Magento 2 Cannot access offset of type string on string in /Converter.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

We are having trouble with one of our magento 2 apps.We are using Magento CLI 2.4.4 PHP 8.1.2 running on Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Everything was working fine until yesterday when we added a few inline translations and a new product. After the cache clear we received this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /var/www/mypage/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/Scope/Converter.php:41
```

The frontend and backend pages are not accessible.

When i try to compile or deploy the error is also show in the command line:

[image]

Can anyone explain what we did wrong or what caused this message? How can we fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to get any further on this before I tear an installation apart?

Comment: @elfling i managed to temporarily avoid this issue. Looks like the problem is connected to loaded settings segments. Inside "public function convert($source) ... foreach ($source as $key => $value)", Somehow one segment of data is undefined (might be connected to the theme that we use). The solution was to just write: if($segmentIndex = 843) { // do nothing } else { $this->_setArrayValue($output, $key, $value); }

Comment: Ah, mine was slightly different. Turned out mine was related to env.php and the setup of consumers